# leaflet.js Zoom to Clicked Feature and then Pan to the Right

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I would like to be able to fitBounds to a feature when you click on it, but when it zooms in I'd like it to take into account a control layer that will appear once zoomed in, and zoom in but just about 150px to the left.  Currently I can accomplish this with the following code, but unfortunately it's not a smooth zoom because my current method will zoom using fitBounds and then once zoomed it uses panBy to pan 150px to the left.  This wouldn't be so bad if the panning was smooth, perhaps maybe after a 250ms wait.  Ideally I would like to be able to do some math on the bounds passed to the fitBounds method to simply account for the 150px shift to the left.

Here is an [example](http://uberbuilder.github.com/choropleth/tests/2013/02/08/hunger-coalition-version-0.1.7/) of what I currently have working.

Here is a simplified version of the code I'm using: (you may click [here](http://uberbuilder.github.com/choropleth/tests/2013/02/08/hunger-coalition-version-0.1.7/) for a fully working version with all of the source code)

**when you click**

```
function clickFeature(e) {
  var layer = e.target;

  map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
}
```

**map on zoomEnd:**

```
map.on({
  zoomend: function() {
    map.panBy([150, 0]);
  }
});
```

So, I've achieved the desired function, but it's just not smooth.

Is there a way to just do some math on the bounds that we're getting for the clicked feature so that when we zoom we zoom into an already modified coordinate, thus eliminating the two-step animation process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can control the animation using pan options. This could help you make the transition smoother.
You can see those [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-panoptions).

Second, you can calculate the offset that you need by using the conversion functions. These can be seen [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-conversion-methods).

For example, you could do something like (off the top of my head) use getBoundsZoom for the map object on the polygon bounds to figure out your future zoom, then use that zoom in the project function with the polygon and create a new LatLngBound from the polygon bound that is slightly offset.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If somebody will please comment here - It's been so long since I've used leaflet.  I'll accept an answer if someone would suggest which one of these is correct.

Comment: I think both are correct. You can either calculate the new bounds by yourself as I referred to or use padding (which is in the animation options that I linked)

Comment: Thanks for responding @hassassin, I selected your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and if was easier than I had thought!
You can set padding on the fitBounds method (and all the pan/zoom methods for that matter)

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitboundsoptions

so:

```
map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds(),{paddingBottomRight:[150,0]});
```

Comment: If somebody will please comment here - It's been so long since I've used leaflet.  I'll accept an answer if someone would suggest which one of these is correct.